# Como inserir hora no Oracle?

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle, timestamp

Eu preciso salvar apenas a hora e minutos (segundos não fazem diferença, então ter ou não, tanto faz) eu devo usar `TIME` ou `TIMESTAMP` ?

Comecei a fazer com `TIMESTAMP(6)`, porém estou com dificuldade em realizar um `insert`, o que eu devo fazer ?

meu insert:

```
INSERT INTO EXEMPLO (DESCRICAO, NUMEROMAXIMO, HORAENTRADA, HORASAIDA) 
 VALUES ('Descrição', '50', '15:51:00', '16:51:00');
```

Comment: Só para esclarecer algumas coisas: Oracle não tem um campo só de horas (time). O tipo de dados date armazena: século, ano, mes ,dia, horas, minutos e segundos. Podes criar essas colunas horaentrada e horasaida do tipo date e inserir uma data tipo: 1-1-1900, e apenas trabalhar com as horas e minutos. A outra opção é recorrer a texto (mas assim complica qualquer conta que queiras fazer com esses valores)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o [TO_DATE](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php);

```
INSERT INTO EXEMPLO (DESCRICAO, NUMEROMAXIMO, HORAENTRADA, HORASAIDA) 
 VALUES ('Descrição', '50', TO_DATE('15:51:00','HH24:MI:SS') , TO_DATE('16:51:00','HH24:MI:SS'))
```

Comment: esse HH24:MI,SS não precisa colocar para o hora saida também ?

Comment: verdade esqueci

Comment: ele me retorna ORA-01722: número inválido

Comment: Você testou direto no oracle?

Comment: Esse campo NUMEROMAXIMO é varchar2 mesmo?

Comment: testei direto no Oracle, o campo numeromaximo é number.

Comment: No meu funcionou